# Isolated subnet on Vmware Workstation for testing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, nat, vmware-workstation

I need to setup a virtual testing lab to test some software updates and group policy changes.
I will be using Vmware Workstation 7. I will setup a Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller/DNS/DHCP/File Server VM and a two or three Windows 7 Professional VMs.

What i want to do is isolate the test network on which those VMs are running (192.168.1.x) from my production network (10.x.x.x) but still make the virtual Domain Controller act as the gateway to provide internet connectivity to the Win7 VMs.

How do i go about configuring that on Vmware workstation and the VMs?

Comment: I know with VMware ESXi (vSphere) you can create a new virtual switch (call it "private" or whatever), give your gateway machine two NICs, and put one of each NIC on the "private" network and your bridged vSwitch that's on your real network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a New Team in Workstation 7 and then add new virtual machines to your team (or existing ones I suppose).  The team will be deployed on a private team LAN.  Your gateway machine will have two virtual NICs like gravyface said.  IMHO your greatest challenge will actually be to have your DC act as a gateway to the net for the other machines.  You will probably need to install a proxy server or perhaps use the Internet Connection Sharing feature to get that done (though that's a different question I suppose).